# Как установить линукс на макбук без usb и cd-rom

Tags: macos, администрирование, install, kali-linux

нет флешки и дисковода. есть iso образ kali linux и макбук с установленной osx Mojave 10.14.6 . можно ли установить линукс рядом с osx  или только линукс что бы остался на макбуке без использования usb  и  cd

Comment: У макбука есть `pxe`?

Comment: да в роде есть , я так думаю! никогда не пользовался маком вот взял попробовать, но все же решил поставить линукс на него

Comment: Ну вот тогда `pxe` - реальное решение проблемы.

Comment: я конечно знаю что ты великам компьютерной науки ноо не мог ли ты быть чуть конкретней_)

Comment: зачем pxe когда есть dd =)

Comment: Какого года мак? Apple запретила такое: https://parg.co/kmw

Comment: Примерно так: https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall

Comment: Конкретнее - это пару экранов текста про то как настраивать pxe. При условии, что на маке это в принципе не запретили. Ну и как написал @Sheridan - вряд ли получится. В чём проблема воткнуть кали в virtualbox?

Comment: @eri вот это интересно, можно поподробней описать процесс

Comment: @Gybernaty тут все просто. Для начала надо установить загрузчик. Например GRUB. Вот тут нужен dd чтоб перезаписать бутсектор. Тут момент важен прописать в нем саму макось. Потом отрезаешь раздел, куда будешь ставить систему. Дальше или луп+исо и цепная загрузка или распаковать лайфсисди и работать как с лайфсиди - для кали это приоритетней, ты ж хакер и не должен оставлять следов. Могу написать как запускай лайфкали, но для начала поставь граб не убив систему, а там задай новый вопрос - скопипасчу параметры запуска

Comment: @donRumata проблема в том, что за@бали эти ограничения и так физика нас ограничивает, я ищу способы свободно пользоваться машиной)))) так как мне записать существующий образ iso на комп не используя внешних носителей, я думаю способ существует, не разочаровывайте меня в русском стеке я вас умоляю!

Comment: Тогда `grub`. Он умеет грузить напрямую из iso.